# Iterate over python class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning how to do OOP with python. I would like to create a class `B` that contains an array/list of class`A` and execute a function in a for loop.

Here is an example:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
    def printSomething(self):
        print (self.name)
        
        
        
        
class B:
    def __init__(self, listOfNames):
        # struture to store a list of objects A based on the list of names supplied
        
    def printSomething2(self):
        for i in # struture to store a list of objects A based on the list of names supplied :
            i.printSomething()
            
            

names = ["a,b,c,d"]

obj = B(names)

obj.printSomething2()
```

what python structure is suitable for storing multiple objects? How can I set the size of it based on the input of the class?
For can I iterate over the created structure to call a function?

Best Regards

Comment: You've already used a list and a for loop so not entirely sure what you're asking

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know how to make it work

Comment: You need to separate each string in the list such as `names = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]`

Answer (score 1):

You could just use:

```
class B():
  def __init__(self,listOfNames):
   self.name_objs = [] 
   for name in listOfNames:
      self.name_objs.append(A(name))
    
   def printSomething2(self):
    for i in self.name_objs:
        i.printSomething()
```

Still this is dynamic and getting the size to set this before is rather hard but this would work

Comment: Print is already called in the `printSomething()` method so it's not necessary to call it in `printSomething2()`

Comment: Edited to be correct